# jquery ajax wont return text and or fire alert on error

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: Return the value of a ajax call to caller function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327024/jquery-return-the-value-of-a-ajax-call-to-caller-function)

In the code below ,

I'm trying to put my ajax call in a function that needs it but makeIt() wont  return "usa from the ajax call ? Or am I going about this all wrong?

```
var makeIt = function () {
    var getStuff = function () {
        return $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "my.php",
          data: {
            id: "2"
          },
          success: function (data) {
            data
          }, // data will return string "usa"
          error: function () {
            alert("error");
          }
        });
      };
    return getStuff();
  };
var result = makeIt() //result should = "usa"
```

Comment: AJAX =  **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML ... the `$.ajax()` function doesnt return a value - it executes a `callback` (`success`) once the execution of the remote url is complete ...

Comment: [Async](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=define%3Aasynchronous)

Comment: @ManseUK I think you are right - my only concern is that the answer to the question you refer to is saying to use `async:false` witch atleast I think is a bad approach.

Comment: @AndreasAL agreed .. perhaps there is a better duplicate ?

Comment: posible diplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just writing `data` in the `success` function doesn't achieve anything.

```
  success: function (data) {
    data
  }
```

It needs to be something like

```
  success: function (data) {
     doSomethingWith(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. $.ajax call is anychronous, there is no way for makeIt to return a value obtained by $.ajax call, you can do this instead:

```
var makeIt = function (callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my.php",
        data: { id: "2" },
        success: callback,
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
};

makeIt(function (result) { 
    //result should = "usa"
});
```

That way, you'll have a nice wrapper around $.ajax call, with all the parameters and error handling provided.

Answer (score 1):

Define "result var" as global var.

Then add extra function to your project.

```
var result;

var makeIt = function () {


    var getStuff = function () {

       return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "my.php",
            data: { id: "2" },
            success: function (data) { fnResult(data) },
            error: function () { alert("error"); }
        });


    };

function fnResult(data){result = data};
```